# Virtualbox 4.3.20 on Debian 7.7 as Host with Windows 7 as guest - can't save excel 2010 file on to external usb drive

Tags: microsoft-excel, usb, virtualbox, debian

Can't save excel 2010 files on to external usb drive:

External usb drive is identified as JMicron USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge [0100] as a "USB device filter".  However saving a text file created in Notepad to USB External HD works fine.

Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ** Also pls note, virtualbox crashes & reboots upon attempting to save an excel 2010 file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it isn't mounted in Linux - use `lsblk` to find the /dev/xxx entry to `umount` in shell - or use any other means that you find convenient.
Note the difference between EJECT (Safely remove, turn off power) and UNMOUNT (leave power on).

But also note that adding the tick to the status indicator (shown below) actually inhibits or unmounts the the USB "drive" (memory for me, on Ubuntu 14.04).

In Virtualbox settings, make sure there is a "ALL" defined (or a specific one if you need that) as shown in the image below.
[image: VB-Settings-USB]

You may still need to enable access to it within the Guest OS by adding a tick in the Virtualbox USB-status display (lower right on screen).
Right click on the USB icon here:
[image: VB Running, USB indicator]

Hope that helps.